# Send signals to processes by name

Tags: python, unix, process, signals

I would like to do the equivalent of `killall -s USR1 termite` in a python script.

Of course I can do `os.system('killall -s USR1 termite')` which works fine, but this doesn't look very elegant to me.

I saw `os.kill()`, but instead of the *name* this takes the *pid* as an argument, which I don't have (also, multiple processes of the same name might exist).

Is there an elegant and pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you always have the subprocess module instead of OS , taking arguments, but if you don't find the the os.system or the call() elegant , I believe you have to implement you own class to create your abstraction layer.

Example with call

```
from subprocess import call

call("killall", "-s", "USR1", "terminate")
```

Comment: This isn't more elegant but at least a bit more flexible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) package to find all processes matching your criteria (such as name). It has a method `send_signal()` (see [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.send_signal)).